# __NSmallocblock__ Amazon AWS Dynamo Error - iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having an issue with Dynamo AWS in which i am trying to fetch the IDs from a database and randomly getting a memory allocation error.
The following is the code that i use to fetch the information:

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                                    accountId:AWSAccountID
                                                                                               identityPoolId:CognitoPoolID
                                                                                                unauthRoleArn:CognitoRoleUnauth
                                                                                                  authRoleArn:CognitoRoleAuth];

//Set the server connection to AWSRegionUSEast1 with the credentials
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                      credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;

NSString *token = FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken;
credentialsProvider.logins = @{ @(AWSCognitoLoginProviderKeyFacebook): token };

//Access the users table with the Facebook ID.
DDBTableRow *tableRow = [DDBTableRow new];
tableRow.UsersHash1ID = [defaults objectForKey:@"UserID"];
tableRow.UsersRange1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"UserID"];

AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];

//Create a load connection to the AWS Dynamo database to find out if the user already exists
[[dynamoDBObjectMapper load:[DDBTableRow class]
                    hashKey:tableRow.UsersHash1ID
                   rangeKey:tableRow.UsersRange1] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (!task.error) {
        DDBTableRow *tableRow = task.result;
        //TODO: Crashes
        if (tableRow.UsersHash1ID == nil) {// if the user does not exist.
            [self firstPlay];
        } else {
            [self SecondPlay]; //If the user exist already in the database.
        }
    } else { //Error handling
        NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
        //TODO: handle the connection

        HUD.textLabel.text = @"Error Connecting to Database";

        [HUD dismissAfterDelay:5.0];

    }
    return nil;
}];
```

And this is the error that i receive: 
[Image Error](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/knowfootballassets/Assets/Screen+Shot+2015-02-18+at+16.04.19.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- load:hashKey:rangeKey:` is an asynchronous method. It means the first `tableRow` object you created could be deallocated before `- load:hashKey:rangeKey:` finishes executing.

You can rewrite this section

```
[dynamoDBObjectMapper load:[DDBTableRow class]
                   hashKey:tableRow.UsersHash1ID
                  rangeKey:tableRow.UsersRange1]
```

to something like

```
[dynamoDBObjectMapper load:[DDBTableRow class]
                   hashKey:[defaults objectForKey:@"UserID"]
                  rangeKey:[defaults objectForKey:@"UserID"]]
```

(You are setting the same value for both hash key and range key. You should make sure that is what you really want.)

If it does not solve the issue, you should enable NSZombie and see what object is deallocated.